# How to generate ID's on my existing data array with 20 id's/users on JavaScript/React

Tags: reactjs

**This is my data.js**. I want to increment the last existing data to plus 1 if I add another user to my table. I used nanoid from my previous generating ids to my userRows data. But I want my id to increment by 1. For example, the last user that I created has an ID of 20 and I want my next user would be 21. Can someone help me or guide me to fix my generating ids? Thank you in advance.

```
export const userRows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: "Richmond",
    fullName: "Richmond Vicente Ramil",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Richmond@gmail.com",
    age: 22,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: "Fernand",
    fullName: "Fernaan Million Galeron",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "passive",
    email: "Fernand@gmail.com",
    age: 23,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    username: "Jerson",
    fullName: "Jerson Tablatin Aganon",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Jerson@gmail.com",
    age: 23,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    username: "Jyvonn",
    fullName: "Jyvonn Nool Juan",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Jyvonn@gmail.com",
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    username: "Mike",
    fullName: "Mike Tyson Kid",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "pending",
    email: "Mike@gmail.com",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    username: "Mark",
    fullName: "Mark Bryant Cleofas",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "passive",
    email: "Mark@gmail.com",
    age: 26,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    username: "Bryan",
    fullName: "Bryan Brenna Tiofelo",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Bryan@gmail.com",
    age: 32,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    username: "Jonathan",
    fullName: "Jonathan Nool Cleofas",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Jonathan@gmail.com",
    age: 19,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    username: "Walter",
    fullName: "Walter Mike Mart",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "pending",
    email: "Walter@gmail.com",
    age: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    username: "Vincent",
    fullName: "Vincent Abdul Saudi",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "pending",
    email: "Vicent@gmail.com",
    age: 42,
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    username: "Galeon",
    fullName: "Galeon Mark Apollo",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Galeon@gmail.com",
    age: 46,
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    username: "Brandon",
    fullName: "Brandon Vicente Ramil",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "passive",
    email: "Brandon@gmail.com",
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    username: "Kenneth",
    fullName: "Kenneth Timothy Sison",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "passive",
    email: "Keneth@gmail.com",
    age: 26,
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    username: "Alexis",
    fullName: "Alexis Delos Santos",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Alexis@gmail.com",
    age: 22,
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    username: "John",
    fullName: "John Kyle Abrera",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "John@gmail.com",
    age: 28,
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    username: "Patrick",
    fullName: "Patrick Martin Nievera",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "pending",
    email: "Patrick@gmail.com",
    age: 23,
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    username: "Steve",
    fullName: "Steve Work Job",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Steve@gmail.com",
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    username: "Ralph",
    fullName: "Ralph Dela Pena",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "passive",
    email: "Ralph@gmail.com",
    age: 46,
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    username: "Chandler",
    fullName: "Chandler Dark Mosquito",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Chandler@gmail.com",
    age: 29,
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    username: "Reyster",
    fullName: "Reyster John Car",
    img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
    status: "active",
    email: "Reyster@gmail.com",
    age: 29,
  },
];
```

**I want to generate ID. if I add a new user, the next id will be 21**

```
const newUser = {
      //I want to put the next id which is 21 here on my newUser object and id property
      //id: ID 21 here ,
      username: addFormData.username,
      img: file
        ? URL.createObjectURL(file)
        : "https://yt3.ggpht.com/CblhnSj8-Q6Ptr6n8Nq1e3wB4gadeNM_IYjDma89iNfuTrAfsMwogvkPFb6JbG8XS-fdBnN5Plk=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo",
      fullName: addFormData.fullName,
      email: addFormData.email,
      age: addFormData.age,
      status: addFormData.status,
    };
```

Comment: A solution for this would be to create a `generateNewId(userRows)` function. Give it the userRows var and the function will return the max id + 1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will receive the last user id and return incremented value, something like that:

```
function generateNewUserId(users) {
  return users[users.length - 1].id + 1;
}

console.log(generateNewUserId(userRows)); // -> "21" for your array
```

If your data is stored on the backend, you can generate the ID there.

By the way, the first option that could come to mind when implementing this, is to use `array.length`, but this could create a mess, if you gonna have DELETE user functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, use a generator function:

```
function* generateId() {
    let count = 0;
    while (true) {
        yield ++count;
    }
}

const iterator = generateId();

const incrementalId = () => {
    const { value } = iterator.next();
    if (value) return value;
    return -1; 
};
```

Now use the `incrementalId` function to generate incremental Ids:

```
export const userRows = [
{
  id: incrementalId(), // 1
  username: "Richmond",
  fullName: "Richmond Vicente Ramil",
  img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin- 
  template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
  status: "active",
  email: "Richmond@gmail.com",
  age: 22,
},
{
  id: incrementalId(), // 2
  username: "Fernand",
  fullName: "Fernaan Million Galeron",
  img: "https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-mui-react-nextjs-admin- 
  template/demo-1/images/avatars/3.png",
  status: "passive",
  email: "Fernand@gmail.com",
  age: 23,
},
// so on...
];

const newUser = {
  id: incrementalId(), // 21 (after invoking incrementalId for 20 times)
  username: addFormData.username,
  img: file
    ? URL.createObjectURL(file)
    : "https://yt3.ggpht.com/CblhnSj8- 
    Q6Ptr6n8Nq1e3wB4gadeNM_IYjDma89iNfuTrAfsMwogvkPFb6JbG8XS-fdBnN5Plk=s88- 
    c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo",
  fullName: addFormData.fullName,
  email: addFormData.email,
  age: addFormData.age,
  status: addFormData.status,
};
```